# Joda-Time duration in exact decimal days

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime

I'm trying to use Joda-Time's duration class to calculate the exact days different between two days. Meaning I would like the result to be something like 25.48 days rather than just 25 days. Right now I have:

```
private static final double MILLISECONDS_IN_DAY = 86400000;

DateTime today = new DateTime();
Duration dur = new Duration(foo.getExpirationDate(), today);
double diff_days = dur.getMillis()/MILLISECONDS_IN_DAY;
```

But I'm wondering if there's a way to combine the 1st and last line into one that just gives me a double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could eliminate the first line by using Joda-Time's constant instead of declaring your own.

```
org.joda.time.DateTimeConstants.MILLIS_PER_DAY
```

Don't forget that if you're trying to calculate another date, there may be a better way to do this. The irregularities in calendars such as leap years are well accounted for within Joda-Time.

Comment: the constant is very helpful, thank you. Do you have an idea of the better way?

Comment: The plus and minus methods of the DateTime object are the best ways to get from one DateTime to another by adding or subtracting a duration or period.

[DateTime.plus(ReadablePeriod period)](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#plus(org.joda.time.ReadablePeriod))

If all you want to do is calculate the number of days between two times, the above code you have will be accurate for any Duration that includes normal length days. If you want perfect accuracy, you should use a Period and convert each element of the period to days then sum them.